# 2-player KeyDown has undesirable behavior

Tags: c#, keypress

I have `Player1Y` and `Player2Y` for two players' `Y` value.

I want `Player1` to decrease its `Y` value when pressing `W` to move it up. Same goes for `Player2` but by pressing `Up`.

I'm using this code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && Player2Y > 0)
    {
        Player2Y -= 5;
        Invalidate();
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && Player1Y > 0)
    {
        Player1Y -= 5;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

The problem is that there are 2 players and when they press `W` and `Up` at the same time, only one player moves depending on who pressed last. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add additional flag for check a change Y by any player. I think if keys *Up* and *W* is pressed  in one event's handler then believe that it is pressed simultaneously. So main that you move only one player in handler event.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool isYChanged = false;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && Player2Y > 0)
    {
        Player2Y -= 5;
        Invalidate();
        isYChanged = true;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && Player1Y > 0 && isYChanged == false)
    {
        Player1Y -= 5;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this first but if Player 2 press UP, Player 1 will never have a chance to move his player again since isYChanged will be true.

I need them to work seperately, I need both players to be moving up and down at the same time depending on what is pressed, Player1 can press W and S, Player 2 can press Up and Down.

Comment: No, Player1Y can move if Player2 don,t pressed Up in current event's handler. All will work.

Comment: The problem is that I need them to be moving at the same time according to what the players have pressed..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a synchronization lock to your code:

```
private System.Object _synchLock = new System.Object();
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{   
    lock(_synchLock)
    {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && Player2Y > 0)
       {
           Player2Y -= 5;
           Invalidate();
       }
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && Player1Y > 0)
       {
           Player1Y -= 5;
           Invalidate();
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda new to programming and I don't know what that synchlock does but I tried to paste it in my code anyways and it stopped their movement completly